# My github repository isn't showing up the languages I used

Tags: github, repository, github-linguist

https://github.com/owdx1/Spring-Boot-2.0-BIL344

My repo doesn't show up the languages I used in the code. Am I doing
something wrong with my file organization? I've tried to apply the solutions from another questions, yet it didn't help.

Thanks :)

Comment: which language didn't show your GitHub?

Comment: I've used spring boot so it's the java language in the application. When the repository is pinned or when it's clicked on, there usually a notation bar that displays the languages that are used the the application. Yet the github doesn't determine the ones I used in this application. I've tried to come up with a solution by looking the similar questions but it didnt work out for me. I am not using github actively, so I couldn't name the issue here.

Comment: which languages are used with Spring boot project..? if you use Java's framework github shows only Java you have used. if you are using java spring boot with jsp then eclipse only shows you have used Java.

Answer (score 0):

Your repository structure is:

```
demo/
.gitattributes
.gitignore
```

The first line of your `.gitattributes` file is:

```
demo linguist-vendored
```

Per [the documentation](https://github.com/github-linguist/linguist/blob/master/docs/overrides.md#vendored-code), that means "please don't count demo in the language statistics". All your code is therefore excluded from statistics.